# jQuery Smooth scrolling WITHOUT the use of ahref

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Due to the way in which my menu is structured, I am unable to use "a href" to scroll to a specific part of my page.

Instead, I am using "

```
<li onclick="location.href='#testimonials';">Testimonials</li>
```

The link works, but it just jumps to the section rather than scrolling to it.

Is there any way to get this smooth scrolling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at this plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Please provide your code or a demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a plugin. You can animate "scrollTop" with jQuery easily:

```
var scrollValue = $("ELEMENT").offset().top; // get position of element
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: scrollValue // scroll to position
}, "slow");
```

To get the anchor you can use .attr()

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    var anchorLink = $(this).attr("href"),
        scrollValue = $(anchorLink).offset().top;
    // Scroll to position    
});
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't wan't to use a[href] for it, you could use data-attributes in your HTML as well, like so:

```
<div data-slideto="#element">Slide to</div>
```

You can get the data-attribute value with jQuery either with .attr("data-slideto") or with .data("slideto")

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
<a class="link" href="#scrollto">scroll</a>
<p style="height: 1000px;"></p>
<div id="scrollto">test</div>

$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetOffset = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
});
```

Here is the corrosponding [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzL4Q/).